# What is the best way to save/load (write/read) data in a text file?

Tags: python, text, save

I've been trying to create a simple game that writes the scores in a text file so later can be read. I use this kind of code to write the scores and a similar one to read the scores:

```
with open('scores.txt', 'a') as record:
    record.write(myData + '\n')
```

This code writes scores line by line. (the way I preferred)

I was wondering if there is a better way of saving the scores on scores.txt?

Comment: If you have many scores in a container, like a list or dictionary, you can save and later read back the whole object in one call to `pickle.dump()` and `pickle.load()`.